# Powershell Renaming loop. Problem with Test-Path not working correctly

Tags: powershell

Trying to get this renaming loop to work and it WILL work starting from an original file without an appended number, but whenever I start from an already numbered file it wont.

My renaming convention is as follows.

```
FILE.TXT
[1]FILE.TXT
[2]FILE.TXT
```

If FILE.TXT is the starting file it works fine, but when I start from [353]FILE.TXT it fails.

```
$number=0
$originalname='[353]TestFile.txt'
$nextname=$originalname

while(Test-Path -LiteralPath "$nextname") {
if ($nextname -match '^\[(\d+)\]') {
$number = [int]$Matches[1]
}
$number++
$originalname -Replace '^\[(\d+)\]',"[$number]"
$nextname=$originalname
}else{
$nextname="[$number]$originalname"
}
Write-Host $nextname
```

EDIT:
My loop needed work, but I got it:

```
$number=0
$originalname='[353]TestFile.txt'
if ($originalname -match '^\[(\d+)\]') {
$number = [int]$Matches[1]
}
$nextname=$originalname
while(Test-Path -LiteralPath "$nextname") {
$number++
if ($nextname -match '^\[(\d+)\]') {
$nextname = $nextname -Replace '^\[(\d+)\]',"[$number]"
}else{
$nextname="[$number]$originalname"
}
}
Write-Host $nextname
```

**Update:** 7/18/23 - I ended up going with a different but still unique naming convention, because using the prior script worked but under heavy testing with nested brackets/parenthesis against hundreds of files, there were random issues even with escape chars added. Non special char version below is very reliable.

```
$number=0
$originalname='TestFile.txt'
if ($originalname -match '^DUPLICATE -(\d+)-') {
$number = [int]$Matches[2]
}
$nextname=$originalname
while(Test-Path -LiteralPath "$nextname") {
$number++
if ($nextname -match '^DUPLICATE -(\d+)-') {
$nextname = $nextname -Replace '^DUPLICATE -(\d+)-',"DUPLICATE -$number-"
}else{
$nextname="DUPLICATE -$number- $originalname"
}
}
Write-Host $nextname
```

Comment: You need to escape `[]`: `... -match '^\[(\d+)\]'`

Comment: Im hitting the match ok and its setting the next number but the loop keeps going like test-path is seeing that the next avail name exists

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I had been switching it and posted it without in my example. But good to be certain ;P